# How to implement nested forms on admin-on-rest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud, admin-on-rest

I'm working on a **CRUD** application where nested forms are needed, all what is done until now were using standard `admin-on-rest` components only.

**An illustrative example:**

I need to create a new question and -in the same form- add all possible responses, with each response item having props like id, value, text, etc.

---

How could I insert a new form or some kind of editable grid? It is possible to do it in some way that does not imply writing a lot of React code, library in which I'm not have all the expertise I would want to have.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Can our new addon helps ? It's a component for displaying input depending on other inputs values in Admin-on-rest: https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input

Comment: Seeing that new component a couple of days ago made me really happy (I'm using it now) **but** what I'm referring to is to some kind of form which allow the user to load more than one child elements. Maybe I'm not being clear enough. I'll make some sketches to explain it better. Thanks a lot!